# Is there any potential downsides to using random UUID as temporary file/directory name?

Tags: random, uuid, temp

Is it reasonable to just use a random UUID (UUID version 4) based on `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom` to name temporary files/directories? The name collision is highly unlikely, but is there any potential problems? Why isn't such scheme used more frequently?

Comment: I don’t see any real problems, but it would make some very long file names. You could have a lower chance of collisions by using 22 characters from `[A-Za-z0-9]` rather than 32 hexadecimal digits. But I guess most people are content with around six random characters and a prefix.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) claims that POSIX “fully portable filenames” can have a maximum length of 14 characters.